# Slow GeoLocation (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I writing app for uwp.

I have code for GeoLocation

here it is

```
 var geoLocator = new Geolocator();
 geoLocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
 Geoposition pos = await geoLocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
 var lat = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
  var lon = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
```

Code launches, when xaml screen opening, but it receive lat and lon very slow(about 30 seconds). When I launch default Weather app for Windows 10 mobile all ok and it found lat and lon very fast (about 1-2 seconds).

What wrong with my code and how I can speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the main point that Weather App doesn't use

```
PositionAccuracy.High
```

because it is sufficient to determine the global location, not your exact whereabouts